# How do I refactor this code with Interfaces, and if so, should I?

Tags: go, interface, coding-style

I'm programming a piece of software that consumes APIs from different services and  the methods would be the same but different execution. I wonder if the code can be organized in interfaces or I just keep working like this:

```
type endPoint struct{
    serverName string
}

func (this *endPoint) getLastDateURL () string{
    if this.Name ="A"{
        return "api.someAWebsite.com/getLastDate"
    }
    if this.Name ="B"{
        return "api.someBWebsite.com/getLastDate"
    }
    return ""
}

func (this *endPoint) processData () output{
    if this.Name ="A"{
        //process in some way
        return
    }
    if this.Name ="B"{
                //process in some different way
                return
    }
    return
}
```

The interface alternative I'm thinking is about this:

```
struct endPoint interface{
    getLastDateURL()
    processData()
}

...
Do each method for each API provider
How would I use it then?
```

My end goal is to have maintainable and clean code. Honestly hate the fact that I'd have to write the same methods for each end point to implement the interface, but perhaps I do not have the Interface concept just so clear yet or there is little advantage in using interfaces in this case with again, the end goal of maintainable and clean code.

Thanks.

Comment: "**Honestly hate the fact that I'd have to write the same methods for each end point to implement the interface**".  Your proposed solution uses kind of switch structure to execute specific code.  Is writing a `func (e *typeX) method()` really so cumbersome compared to `if e.Name == "X"`?  This is why we have polymorphism in language: So you don't need to write a big switch structure to run different code for different values, and you can closely collect each coherent set of code together rather than having everything intermixed throughout your "master" procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// "struct endPoint interface" is invalid, and signatures are missing their return types:
type endPoint interface{
    getLastDateURL() string
    processData() output
}
```

> How would I use it then?

I can't give a complete solution since you haven't shown how you're using your current code, but in general you'd have:

- Something that instantiates an implementation - whatever would be setting `Name` in the current implementation would instead create an instance of a concrete type implementing `endPoint`
- Something that calls `getLastDateURL` and/or `processData` - instead of receiving an `*endPoint` *struct*, it would receive an `endPoint` *interface value*, and then wouldn't care what the underlying implementation is; it would just call the methods, pretty much just like it does today

> My end goal is to have maintainable and clean code.

This is probably a good way to achieve that, but it depends on context not shown in the question.

> Honestly hate the fact that I'd have to write the same methods for each end point to implement the interface

You're *already* writing an implementation for each end point, you're just writing them all in the same methods. The amount of code you have to write is almost identical, but the resulting code is cleaner & more organized - for example, each concrete implementation could be in its own file, rather than having to be all in the same methods. With many/complex providers, your current solution becomes increasingly difficult to navigate if you ever need to change it or add a provider.

Answer (score -1):

Use the [double dispatch pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch):

Define a typed func on endPoint for each class it supports.

Define an interface that has a func that accepts an endPoint object.

Have all classes that want to use endPoint implement that interface’s func and pass themselves to the typed endPoint method.

To invoke it, call the interface method passing endPoint.

IMHO you should do it.

Comment: Why overcomplicate this with double-dispatch and callback funcs? This doesn't seem to have any advantage over the much more intuitive use of an interface and an implementation per endpoint.

Comment: @Adrian double dispatch is used exactly and only for this situation where you have a giant block of ifs that must be magically maintained, and is actually less code and bug free because the block of ifs is eliminated in favour of strong typing and the compiler doing all the work.

Comment: "the block of ifs is eliminated in favour of strong typing and the compiler doing all the work" is exactly what you get just using interfaces; the addition of double dispatch with callbacks seems unnecessary, unidiomatic, and overcomplicated.

Comment: @Adrian not so. Your approach requires that each parameter object have knowledge of how to “process in some way”, which is significantly different to OP’s paradigm. Double dispatch leaves the responsibility and maintenance of each different action in its own func in the code being called, not in the code of the parameter.

Comment: What they have right now is one method with all the implementations in it. That can be easily split into a type per endpoint, with each having only the implementation for that endpoint. That's the only change. The end result is no change at all to OP's paradigm; they still call the same methods, in the same ways. The calling code could potentially be completely unchanged save for replacing `*endPoint` with `endPoint`. Double dispatch and callbacks don't solve anything here, it would only add complexity.